# Перевод кода с циклом из Pascal в Python

Tags: python, pascal

Нужно перевести этот код из *Pascal* в *Python*:

```pascal
var n, n2, n5, n10, c: integer;
begin
  write('n = ');
  readln(n);
  c := 0;
  for n10 := 0 to n div 10 do
    for n5 := 0 to n div 5 do
      for n2 := 0 to n div 2 do
        if n - 10 * n10 - 5 * n5 - 2 * n2 >= 0
          then inc(c);
  writeln('Способов: ', c);
  readln
end.
```

---

Я сделал такой перевод, но он не правильный, т.к выдает совершенно другие значения при одинаковых входных данных:

```python
n = int(input())
c = 0
for n10 in range (0, n // 10):
    for n5 in range (0, n // 5):
        for n2 in range (0, n // 2):
            if n - 10 * n10 - 5 * n5 - 2 * n2 >= 0:
                c = c + 1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что в пайтоне `range` исключает
последний индекс:

```python
n = int(input())
c = 0
for n10 in range (0, n // 10 + 1):
    for n5 in range (0, n // 5 + 1):
        for n2 in range (0, n // 2 + 1):
            if n - 10 * n10 - 5 * n5 - 2 * n2 >= 0:
                c = c + 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Хм, очень логичное поведение...

Answer (score 2):

Порадуйте преподавателя переводом на Python в функциональном стиле:

```
from itertools import product,  starmap
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul,add
n = int(input("n="))
c = [1  for set_ in product(range (n//10 + 1), range(n//5 + 1), range(n//2 + 1)) \ 
        if n - reduce(add,starmap(mul, zip([10,5,2], list(set_))))>=0].__len__()
print(c)
```

здесь мы создаем список в который добавляется число  "1" при выполнении требуемого условия, а потом мы вычисляем его длину. В Python для списка `a` авполняется  `len(a) == a.__len__()`.
Так что если не считать импортов то решение вышло в одну затейливую строчку ))